# Build list of plucked attributes from belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, belongs-to

Active Record ninjas,

I'm looking for a concise Rails way to get attributes out of an associated model.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :captain, class_name: User
```

Get array of unique captains who are associated with a team:

```
Team.all.map(&:captain_id).uniq
```

What I'd like to do is take that unique list of Captains and grab each one's `first_name` and `last_name`.

I want to do

```
Team.all.map(&:captain_id).uniq.pluck(:first_name, :last_name)
```

But `pluck` doesn't work with arrays. I can do this in a couple steps but what's the Rails way?

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL ?

Comment: `User.where(id: Team.all.select(:captain_id)).pluck(:first_name, :last_name)`

Comment: @MrYoshiji just `Team.pluck(:captain_id)` works as well

Comment: @MrYoshiji - Yes PostgreSQL.

Comment: @MrYoshiji - your 1st response works great. make it into an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
captain_ids = Team.all.select(:captain_id)
User.where(id: captain_ids).pluck(:first_name, :last_name)
```

Rails should be smart enough to do a nested select.

The other option is the `joins`, it can be more efficient (faster), but in my test cases a sub-select was 3 times faster than an `INNER JOIN`. Try it out yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `joins` and `group`:

```
Team.joins(:captain)
    .group("users.id")
    .pluck("users.first_name", "users.last_name")
```

Comment: I get errors even at `Team.joins(:captain).group("captains.id")`: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "captains"`